# VBA Function to Return Collection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to return a type `Collection` from a function and I am getting the error:

> Compile error:
>
> Invalid use of property

Here is the below code that's I created to test the function. I know the collection is filling correctly as I've testing a run through of the collection and output all values; which all came out as intended.

**QUESTION:**

Why is this error occurring? And what's the best approach to fix it?

```
Sub testingFunc()

   Dim ErrorCodes As Collection
   Set ErrorCodes = New Collection

   Set InitializeErrorCodes = ErrorCodes '<--- Where my error is occurring when trying to retrieve the collection

End Sub
```

And here is the code initializing my `Error Codes`

```
Function InitializeErrorCodes() As Collection '<--- Where I'm trying to return the collection

   Dim ErrorCodes As Collection
   Set ErrorCodes = New Collection

   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "CSD_ERR_120", "Multiple products in a case is invalid"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "CSD_ERR_128", "Invalid Store with Zero Allocation"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_101", "Purchase Order Status Notification"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_104", "Tolerance Violation - Overshipment"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_110", "Multiple Open Lines found for Product on PO"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_111", "Tolerance Violation - short shipment"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_112", "Tolerance Violation - Number of Store/SKU Discrepancies Exceeded"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_114", "Product (casepack) Mismatch on one or more product identifiers"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_115", "Product (Bulk) Mismatch on one or more product indentifiers"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_116", "No Open Line was found. PO contains a line in Cancel Status for Product"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_117", "Early Shipping Date Violation"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_118", "PO Cancel Date Violation || Passed Cancel Date"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "DET_ERR_125", "Duplicate vendor case number"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "HDR_ERR_101", "Duplicate Vendor ASN Number"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "PRE_ERR_105", "Invalid Prepack configuration. Failed - Missing Component SKU(s)"
   AddToErrorCollection ErrorCodes, "PRE_ERR_106", "Product Quantity does not equal the sum of the case quantities"

   Set InitializeErrorCodes = ErrorCodes

End Function
```

Below is the function in conjunction with above to add to the collection

```
Private Sub AddToErrorCollection(Col As Collection, eName As String, eDescription As String)

   Dim NewErrorCode As cErrorCodes
   Set NewErrorCode = New cErrorCodes
   NewErrorCode.name = eName
   NewErrorCode.description = eDescription

   Col.Add NewErrorCode

End Sub
```

Comment: InitializeErrorCodes is a function, not a property, and you are trying to use it as a property. Correct call should be `Set ErrorCodes = InitializeErrorCodes`. And since InitializeErrorCodes does the collection initialization, you should drop the `Set ErrorCodes = New Collection` in `testingFunc`

Comment: @VincentG My oh my... not sure how I missed such a newbie mistake... Got a little rusty after a couple week break apparently. Thanks for spotting that out for me! Can you post as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InitializeErrorCodes` is a function, not a property, but you are trying to use it as a property.
Correct call should be `Set ErrorCodes = InitializeErrorCodes`.

And since InitializeErrorCodes does the collection initialization, you should drop the `Set ErrorCodes = New Collection` in `testingFunc`.